# Issues with geom_error_bar and conditional shape in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of data frames (split in list) and I am creating line charts (one for each df) which shows open symbols (point shape "1") for data that is not detected (e.g. below limit of detection) and filled symbols (point shape "16") to represent detected data (mean and std).

Here is some reproducible data to work with:

```
OutdoorAir <- data.frame(
  "Sample" = c("Air", "Air", "Air", "Air","Aerosol", "Aerosol", "Aerosol", "Aerosol"), 
  "Date" = c("1980", "1990", "2000", "2010", "1980", "1990", "2000", "2010"), 
  "Value" = c(331, 250, 484, 221, 545, 131, 417, 476),
  "Locality" = c("Paris", "Lyon", "Paris", "Lyon", "Paris", "Lyon", "Paris", "Lyon"),
  "Less.Than" = c("<","<","","<","","","<",""),
  "Uncertainty" = c(NA,NA,45,NA,10,8,NA,71),
  "Nuclides" = c("K-40","K-40", "K-40", "K-40", "C-14", "C-14", "C-14", "C-14"))

OutdoorAir_l <- split(OutdoorAir,list(OutdoorAir$Sample,OutdoorAir$Locality, OutdoorAir$Nuclides), drop=TRUE)
lapply(names(OutdoorAir_l), function(i){
  ggplot(OutdoorAir_l[[i]], aes(Date, Value, group = Nuclides, col = as.factor(Nuclides))) +
    colorization +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Value-Uncertainty, ymax=Value+Uncertainty), color = "black") +
    geom_point() +
    scale_shape_manual(values=ifelse("Less.Than" == "<",c(1),c(15)), guide = "none") +
    ggsave(paste(i, ".png", sep = ""),  dpi = 100, width = 30, height = 20, units = "cm")
})
  dev.off()
```

If the analysis is below the detection limit, the column "Less.than" is filled with "<" and the "Value" is actually the detection limit (should appear as an open circle in my figure)

Otherwise, it's Value (mean) and Uncertainty (std).

What's wrong with my  `scale_shape_manual` function ?

[image]

Moreover, sometimes the error bar appears as a vertical line with two horizontal lines (Figure 1) while in most of the cases, a single vertical line is visible (Figure 2). Any idea ?
[image]

Comment: Hi Sylvain. Could you check your example data please? One of your vectors has nine elements and the rest have eight, so it is not reproducible. Also, we cannot split your data frame because you are splitting by a column called Nuclides that your data frame doesn't contain. The plots you have included also suggest that your real dates are actual R date objects, whereas you have used simple strings for years, which will produce a discrete axis if we try to plot them. I applaud you including an example, but please ensure it is reproducible and that it replicates your problem. Thanks.

Comment: `"Less.Than"` is a character constant.  So is  `"<"`.  So `"Less.Than" == "<"` is always `FALSE`.  The `values` parameter to `scale_shape_manual` should define one value for each entry of the legend, not each row of the dataset.  And @AllanCameron beat me to the other points I was going to make.  Keep trying.  You'll get there!

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your remarks, I've corrected the reproducible example